# Add background color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

HI i have a dynamic li in my django template

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function setSize(size) {
        document.getElementById('id_option1').value = size;
    }

    function notavailable(notavai) {
        alert('selected product is not available');
    }
</script>
```

```
{% for i in prosize %}
    {% if i.num_in_stock > 0 %}
        <li><a id="{{i.option1}}1" ref="javascript:setSize('{{i.option1}}')">{{i.option1}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

i need to add the **background** **color** to **active** a **link**  **onclick**  i am **already** using a javascript function on a .Please suggest how can i do this

Comment: What exactly you want? You want when the user click on your link, change the background color of it?

Comment: yes exactly what i want

Comment: I've added my answer, if you are using jQuery, you can write the function better, I'm currently write it and will update my answer soon `;)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3YLd/6/)**

So, it's easy, in HTML markup you have:

```
<a class="order" id="{{i.option1}}" href="javascript:setSize('{{i.option1}}')">{{i.option1}}</a>
```

- Note that I've changed the `id`. I deleted the `1` from at the end of it.
- Also the `href` attribute you wrote, was invalid. I've correct it.
- Also, I've added a class to it for furthur usage.

And change your `setSize` function to this:

```
// because IE9 (and below) doesn't support for getElementsByClassName
// we use this funciton instead
// written by Jonathan Snook
// http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/your_favourite_1
function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}

function setSize(size) {
    // i just comment this line as i don't know what it doesyourself
    // document.getElementById('id_option1').value = size;

    // change the color the others to transparent
    var others = getElementsByClassName(document, 'order');
    for (var i = 0, l = others.length; i < l; i++) {
        others[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    }

    // this line will change the background color of your element
    document.getElementById(size).style.backgroundColor = '#ff6600';
}
```

---

### jQuery

If you are using jQuery, there is no need to use javascript internally, let's jQuery handle all them for you.
Write this code in your `.js` file:

```
$(function () {
    // get al links and attach the `click` handler to them
    $('.order').on('click', function (e) {
        // prevent default behaviour of link
        e.preventDefault();

        // get size and do something with it
        var size = $(this).attr('data-size');
        $('#textbox').val(size);

        // change the color the others to transparent
        $('.order').css('background-color', 'transparent');

        // change the color of link
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff6600');
    });
});
```

- You can check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3YLd/4/).

Comment: i have use this it works fine document.getElementById(size).style.backgroundColor = '#ff6600';
but it makes all background change a on click, i need only one at a time to be highlighted

Comment: @user2106353 You didn't mention it before, I've updated my answer, check it (don't forget to change the HTML markup). I've added a class to your links.

Comment: @user2106353 You're welcome, I change the JavaScript method for compatibility with IE too, don't miss it `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want should not be implemented in javascript or python but CSS. You should use `:active` selector in CSS.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Answer (score 0):

in your loop, you can also bind the on click event and pass the id ...like

```
{% for i in prosize %}
    {% if i.num_in_stock > 0 %}
        <li><a id="{{i.option1}}1" onclick='ChangeColor('+{{i.option1}}1+')' ref="javascript:setSize('{{i.option1}}')">{{i.option1}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

function ChangeColor(id)
{
    $("#"+id).css("background","#fff");
}
```